# Store a pointer to lisp object in system area memory

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

I want to use Common Lisp to process something for a C program. But for some reasons I need use SBCL.

I wonder how to correctly store a pointer to lisp object in system area memory which is allocated by a C function. For example,

```
struct c_struct {
    ...
    lispobj *obj;
    ...
};
```

With `sb-kernel:get-lisp-obj-address`, I can get the pointer to a lisp object. But it makes no sence to store it in foreign memory. The main problem is that GC moves objects. `sb-sys:with-pinned-object` only pins objects during the extent of the body and it's obviously a bad idea to pin a object for a long time. So I need some methods to tell GC to update the pointer when the pointed object is moved.

Comment: The answer to "[is it] possible to store a pointer to lisp object in system area memory which is allocated by a C function?" is either going to be "yes" or "no".  You'll be more likely to get a useful answer if you can show some code that does something like what you want, and indicate what, specifically, you'd like to do differently.

Comment: Since you're using SBCL, you should also have a look at the manual, particularly chapter [8 Foreign Function Interface](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/index.html#Foreign-Function-Interface).  You'll find lots of information about how to access foreign values, how to dereference pointers, etc.

Comment: I have edited my post. I have read the manual. But it doesn't say anything about storing lisp object in foreign memory.

Answer (score 1):

While I don't believe (although I'm eager to be corrected) that SBCL allows one to "pin" the pointer-address of an object for a very long time, nor is the garbage collector easily extensible to updating “foreign copies” of pointers to objects, you *can* obtain a persistent pointer to a Lisp callback function; i.e. a pointer which a C program can `funcall` which is actually a Lisp function, using `defcallback`.

One (untested) theory might be to wrap your C language calls in such a way:

- C function allocates `c_struct` with a NULL pointer slot
- You provide a `(defcallback …)` function pointer to your C program; 
  let's call it `void with_locked_access ((void*) interior_function(struct c_struct *), struct c_struct *struct_to_use)`
- when C function(s) want to access this pointer, they call `interior_function` with their own function-pointer `interior_function` and the pointer to the `c_struct` that interests them
- `interior_function` is actually `(defcallback call-c-with-pinned-object…)`; it, in turn, calls `sb-sys:with-pinned-object` and obtains the system-area pointer for the object, and stores it into `c_struct` before calling `interior_function` with the (now-populated) structure as its parameter.
- `interior_function` does whatever it is that it wants the pinned Lisp object for; it returns, and `call-c-with-pinned-object` closes out the `with-pinned-object` form and returns, itself.

Naturally, this depends entirely upon what it is you want to do in your C code, and whether it's going to be running in parallel with Lisp code that might be negatively impacted by the pinning, &c &c.

Alternatively, in the special (but common) case that the object in question happens to be a byte vector (e.g. perhaps a buffer of some kind), you might be able to take advantage of `cffi-sys:make-shareable-byte-vector` and `cffi-sys:with-pointer-to-vector-data`, q.v.

Comment: But how can call-c-with-pinned-object knows which object an instance of  c_struct refers to? If it's obtained by looking up a name stored in c_struct, the implementation can't be more efficient than just save the name in c_struct. The good point of using a pointer is that object can be found in constant time.

Comment: The lisp object is unlikely to be a byte vector. If the object can be easily represented in foreign data struct, it would better store the object directly in foreign memory pointed by c_struct.